# A simple proof that a real differentiable local section of a holomorphic function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is motivated by [Define a branch cut of the argument depending on z](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607899). In the answer a branch of the logarithm $\ln_A : U  \to \mathbb C$ on a domain $U \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is defined based on a branch $A : U \to \mathbb R$ of the argument function (which is a continuous function such that $\lvert z \rvert e^{iA(z)} = z$ for all $z \in U$) via
$$\ln_A(z) = \ln^{\mathbb R}(\lvert z \rvert) + iA(z) .$$
The function $\ln_A$ is obviously continuous and satisfies $e^{\ln_A(z)} = z$ for all $z \in U$. There are various approaches to prove that $\ln_A$ is *holomorphic*. The most elegant approach is probably to invoke the inverse function theorem for the complex exponential function as in the answer to the linked question, but the OP asked for a more elementary alternative proof not using the inverse function theorem.

This was done in two steps:

1. Proving that $A$ is real differentiable which can easily be done by using the fact that $\cos(A(z)) + i\sin(A(z)) = \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}$. This immediately implies that $\ln_A$ is a real differentiable local section of the exponential function.
2. Proving that $\ln_A$ is complex differentiable based on 1.

For 2. one can verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but this is a tedious job. Alternatively one can use the following lemma:

> Let $U, V \subset \mathbb C$ be open and $s : U \to \mathbb C, f : V \to \mathbb C$ be functions such that $s(U) \subset V$ and $(f \circ s)(z) = z$ for all $z \in U$ (this means that $s$ is a *local section of $f$*). If $s$ is real differentiable at $z_0 \in U$ and $f$ is complex differentiable at $w_0 = s(z_0)$, then $s$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$.

This seems to be interesting in its own right. The purpose of this question is to give a proof.

Comment: $s$ continuous is enough since then an easy argument shows that outside the preimages of the critical points  of $f$ (which are discrete since $s$ continuous and injective so the preimage under $s$ of a discrete set is discrete) we have that $s$ is a local continuous inverse of $f$ hence holomoprhic, while $s$ is bounded (continuity)near any of those preimages so they are removable singularities

Comment: @Conrad You are right. I used this method in my answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607899, but the OP asked for an alternative approach. See the update of the question.

Comment: @Conrad Would you like to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4611320?

Comment: done, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We identify $\mathbb C$ with the real vector space $\mathbb R^2$ and let
$Ds(z_0) : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ and $Df(w_0) : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ denote the real derivatives of $s$ at $z_0$ and of $f$ at $w_0$. Both are $\mathbb R$-linear maps; $Df(w_0)$ is even $\mathbb C$-linear. Since $f \circ s = id$ on $U$, the chain rule shows that
$$Df(w_0)\circ Ds(z_0) = D(f \circ s)(z_0) = Did(z_0) = id .\tag{1}$$
Since $Df(w_0)$ is $\mathbb C$-linear, we have $Df(w_0)(v) = a \cdot v$ for some $a \in \mathbb C$. Clearly $a \ne 0$ because the zero-map cannot satisfy $(1)$. We conclude $a \cdot Ds(z_0)(u) = u$ for all $u \in \mathbb C$, thus $Ds(z_0)(u) = a^{-1} \cdot u$ for all  $u \in \mathbb C$. This shows that $Ds(z_0)$ is $\mathbb C$-linear. Thus $s$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$.